# Erlang analog to RoR CookieStore Session storage

Tags: authentication, cookies, erlang, cryptography, session-cookies

I trying to add authentication module to web application (by web application i mean webmachine app, but think that if solution exists, it is applicable to any other framework). After user has been successfully logged in i start new session and save SID into cookies. I want to try new approach with cryptographically signed cookies, like in [Ruby](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html)(section 2.5 Session Storage). Is there any libraries for this, or advice some erlang facilities for this?

Comment: I think that question may be closed: erlang's module `public_key` fits my needs.